# Creating an image map for SharePoint

Tags: image-display, html5

What is the simplest and least technical way to have an image with clickable regions/hot-spots that users would be able to do themselves?

Answer (score 0):

That depends how technical savvy your users are.
Most Front-end developers can't even do it without help...(or know what an Imagemap is)

- The creation part requires displaying the image and interact with it
  You could steal the code from Imagemap Generator sites
- You need to save the MAP data somewhere
  You want this as tight to the mapped IMG itself, preferably stored in the same field, so the available Picture Column is of nu use.
- On display you need to add the MAP data to the page
  A standard Picture Library just displays the IMG, no way of adding the `useMap` attribute.
  So you need to develop custom code for displaying you IMG

That all could be the reason why not many frontenders use Imagemaps

To answer your question.

The least technical way is to use an [Imagemap Generator site](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/), and copy/paste the code as (HTML) page content.